# Error in code after reading data from file with the help of fstream

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

While creating a simple stock management system, I encountered some problem after adding a new item in the list. My code will explain better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; // For sake of speed

class INVENTORY
{
    char name[10];
    int code;
    float cost;

public:
    void setData();
    void getData();
};

void INVENTORY ::setData()
{
    std::cout << "Enter Name: ";
    std::cin.getline(name, 10);
    std::cout << "Enter Code: ";
    std::cin >> code;
    std::cout << "Enter Cost: ";
    std::cin >> cost;
}

void INVENTORY::getData()
{
    cout << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(10) << name << setw(10) << code << setw(5) << cost << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    INVENTORY item;
    fstream inoutfile;

    inoutfile.open("STOCK.DAT", ios::ate | ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    inoutfile.seekg(0, ios::beg); // go to beginning.

    cout << "CURRENT CONTENTS OF STOCK" << '\n';
    while (inoutfile.read((char *)&item, sizeof(item)))
    {
        item.getData();
    }
    inoutfile.clear(); // clears the eof state flag.
    cout<<'\n'<<inoutfile.good()<<'\n';
    /* ADD more items */

    cout << "\nAdd an item: \n";
    item.setData();
    char ch;
    cin.get(ch);
    inoutfile.write((char *)&item, sizeof(item));
    cout<<'\n'<<inoutfile.good()<<'\n';

    // Display the appended file
    inoutfile.seekg(0);
    cout << "CONTENTS OF APPENDED FILE\n";
    while (inoutfile.read((char *)&item, sizeof(item)))
    {
        item.getData();
    }
    cout<<'\n'<<inoutfile.good()<<'\n';
    // Find the number of objects in the file.

    int last = inoutfile.tellg();
    int n = last / sizeof(item);

    cout << "Number of Objects: " << n << endl;
    cout << "Total bytes in file: " << last << endl;

    /* Modify the details of an item */

    cout << "Enter object number to be updated: ";
    int object;
    cin >> object;
    cin.get(ch);
    int location = (object - 1) * sizeof(item);

    if (inoutfile.eof())
    {
        inoutfile.clear();
    }
    inoutfile.seekp(location);
    cout << "Enter the new values of objects \n";
    item.setData();
    cin.get(ch);

    inoutfile.write((char *)&item, sizeof item) << flush;

    /* SHOW UPDATED FILE */
    cout << "Contents of updated file: \n";
    while (inoutfile.read((char *)&item, sizeof item))
    {
        item.getData();
    }

    inoutfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I reused the class from some file, please don't sue me for `using namespace std` I don't use it usually, but used today for sake of speed.

The 3rd `cout<<'\n'<<inoutfile.good()<<'\n';` returns false and I am not able to figure out why this happens. I already have the file `STOCK.DAT` and there is data already present in it (of the same type). The relevant output:

```
CURRENT CONTENTS OF STOCK
Apple     5         50   
Banana    6         80   

1

Add an item: 
Enter Name: Pineapple
Enter Code: 8
Enter Cost: 150

1
CONTENTS OF APPENDED FILE
Apple     5         50   
Banana    6         80   
Pineapple 8         150  

0 // something is not good here but what?
Number of Objects: -858993460
Total bytes in file: -1
```

There are more elements in output but I showed you the relevant output, `tellg` returns false, so there is definitely something wrong and I can't figure it out.

I will explain what is happening over here:

- I made a class named `INVENTORY` and made a few members and member functions in it.
- Then in the main function, I made a `fstream` object and opened a file named `STOCK.DAT`, with a few additional flags.
- Then I point the get pointer to the beginning (both pointers move together for a fstream object).
- The file is in binary so I print out what's already present in the file.
- Then I use `clear()` to remove `eof` flag and check whether everything is right, which will result true here.
- Then I add another item to the end of file and check whether everything is good, true over here also.
- Then I set the get pointer to beginning to print all the data in the file again and now everything is not `good` and I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question, and add the observations you made, when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger please?

Comment: Um I have, there are comments for almost everything in code, I also stated that error appeared in 3rd `good` and there was not error in 2nd `good`. So that means there is an error between 2nd and 3rd `good` statement. What more should I add?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I tried to explain, I am not sure how to debug in vscode, please look once, I am stuck with this for many hours.

Comment: try removing ios::ate param from the open function and explicitly specifying the file pointer whenever needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. After reaching `eof` if you try to do `inoutfile.tellg()` it will return `-1`. Instead use `inoutfile.clear()` to clear the `eof` tag and then use `inoutfile.tellg()`.